# How to set Pc so that it will not save anything for a period in Ubuntu?

Tags: security

I want such a setting or command so that if I set a period(i.e. 10.00 am to 11.00 am) the computer will not save any thing I will work in this period.

Comment: You could use a cron script to remount all file systems as read only at 10.00 and then mount them as read/write at 11.00

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to login as guest user in Ubuntu during the period and your changes won't be saved on the machine.

If you want to use root and have the feature, then moreover it all depends on the work you are doing on the computer. If you are browsing the web, then use it in private window option. Or save whatever you download or read to a single folder and write a script to delete the folder and add it in crontab so that it will run exactly at 11 and clear the folder.